# What is the writer trying to convey?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"Although I cannot claim any experience or substantial knowledge in the area of language pedagogy, I do recognize how essential it is."
 And
"the applied, pedagogical side outstrips the theoretical side in terms of intrinsic importance, numbers of practitioners, and the securing of institutional tolerance. "
"I see the effectiveness of pedagogical applications as an important empirical test for linguistic theories. My suspicion is that, in the long run, cognitive grammar will not fare badly in this regard."

Comment: @KJO "... to prove their grasp (or otherwise) of the possibly preceding text"

Answer (score 1):

> Although I cannot claim any experience or substantial knowledge in the area of language pedagogy, I do recognize how essential it is.

*Although I have no experience or knowledge of how language is taught, I recognize that the study of language teaching is important*

> the applied, pedagogical side outstrips the theoretical side in terms of intrinsic importance, numbers of practitioners, and the securing of institutional tolerance.

*The application of teaching methods, and their study, is fundamentally more  important than theorizing. The number of people who study actual teaching methods is more than the number of people who study theories of teaching. Finally, universities or large organizations more readily accept the applied aspect (as opposed to the theoretical aspect) of teaching.*

> I see the effectiveness of pedagogical applications as an important empirical test for linguistic theories. My suspicion is that, in the long run, cognitive grammar will not fare badly in this regard

*The study of teaching methods is important to generate actual, measurable data to test linguistic theories. I suspect that, in the long run, disciplines such as cognitive grammar would be strengthened by the data generated by these efforts*

Comment: Thank you so much. How do you understand that? For me, it literally hard to interpret.

Comment: One word at a time. It is difficult text. Sometimes, I try to practice reader "harder" text, like Nietzsche...

Comment: What do you mean "one word at a time"? You don't get every words?

Answer (score -2):

> I've never taught language arts, but I can tell that language does need to be taught.
>
> When we compare the practice of teaching language to advances in language theory, teaching wins.  Its value is more obvious, there are more teachers than theorists, and teaching is the skill-set that schools want to support.
>
> How well things work in the classroom is a good way to evaluate (competing) linguistic theories.  Cognitive grammar should (eventually) work very well in the classroom.